# Remove Sink in Effect in Tabbar(Iphone Development)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar

Is it possible to remove the sink-in effect in Tab-Bar?

I mean the button will be selected without a sink-in effect.

Comment: before you do that make sure its not against the HIG

Comment: I don't see how this is related to either cocos2d or the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. To do so, subclass the UITabBarItem class and override the appropriate methods. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698094/uitabbaritem-highlight-state-image) for more.